# Matlab cell array parsing

Tags: matlab

I have a large cell array and I'm trying to vectorize some string parsing.  The cell is 100000 x 1 and looks like this:

```
data =   
'"2016-07-27T14:18:08.519Z"'  
'"2016-07-27T14:18:16.549Z"'  
'"2016-07-27T14:18:21.544Z"'  
'"2016-07-27T14:18:27.517Z"'
```

I want to parse this into two cell arrays that look like this:

`date_str`, which would look like this:

```
'2016-07-27'  
'2016-07-27'  
'2016-07-27'  
'2016-07-27'
```

`time_str`, which would look like this:

```
'14:18:08.519'  
'14:18:16.549'  
'14:18:21.544'  
'14:18:27.517'
```

I have looked at using `cellfun(@strsplit,data)`, but it doesn't let me specify a delimiter for the "strsplit" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to remove the double quotes, and then [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) (with the `'split'` option) to split at the desired character. I'm assuming the splitting criterion is simply the occurrence of `'T'`.

```
data = regexprep(data, '^"|"$',''); % remove double quotes
result = regexp(data, 'T', 'split'); % split at 'T'
result = vertcat(result{:}); % un-nest cell array
date_str = result(:,1);
time_str = result(:,2);
```